# /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt is expired, How to renew it?

Tags: kubernetes

The `kubernetes` cluster in on 1.21.2. The `kubelet` is also on 1.21.2

```
kubelet --version
Kubernetes v1.21.2

kubeadm version
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"21", GitVersion:"v1.21.2", GitCommit:"092fbfbf53427de67cac1e9fa54aaa09a28371d7", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-06-16T12:57:56Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.5", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

When i am trying to "`kl get no`" I am getting below error

```
kl get no
error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
**Note: kl is alias of kubectl**
I checked my /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt and it was expired.
```

In kubelet.crt, the issuer is below

```
Subject: CN=aparapu@1591592441
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
```

Need help in renew this kubelet.crt.

Comment: Hi shaktirath welcome to S.F. Without knowing more about how you provisioned your Node, no one can say _for sure_ but in _most cases_ `rm -rf /var/lib/kubelet && rm -rf /etc/kubernetes && systemctl restart kubelet.service` will cause kubelet to go back through the initial cert request process and the apiserver will either prompt you or auto-approve the Node's cert request. Feel free to use `mv` instead of `rm`, and optionally stop kubelet first

Comment: Why to remove the /etc/kubernetes? I provisioned the node through kubeadm, which is present in kubernetes documentation.

Comment: Just to add one more thing, kubeadm renew cert is not for /var/lib/kubelet/kubelet.crt. If you are still sure then give me the detail steps.

Comment: Hi @shaktirath, if I good understand your question [manual certificate renewal](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#manual-certificate-renewal) should help you. Try to exec `kubeadm certs renew`.

Comment: This above link is not talking about anything, how to renew the /var/lib/kubelet/kubelet.crt.
I tried below link also but unfortunately my kubectl is not working.
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#kubelet-serving-certs

Comment: How did you set up your cluster? Are you using bare metal or some cloud providor? Look also at [this similar issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/2186)

Comment: Yes. My cluster is made up of bare metal.

Answer (score 10):

I've seen this issues in many other forums, and I finally found a solutions that works from me.

First, my issues was purely due to the certificate `/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt`, which I can see expired with either:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect localhost:10250 2>&1 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | openssl x509 -text -noout | grep -A 2 Validity
```

or

```
sudo openssl x509 -in /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt -text -noout  | grep -A 2 Validity
```

First, you need to enable `--rotate-certificates=true` and `--rotate-server-certificates=true` in your kubelet. In my case, I installed the cluster using `kubeadm`, so I can edit the `/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/10-kubeadm.conf`, and add the following to `KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS`:

```
Environment="KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS=--rotate-certificates=true --rotate-server-certificates=true --tls-cipher-suites=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256"
```

In general, it is just adding these flags to the kubelet exeuction `/usr/bin/kubelet --rotate-certificates=true --rotate-server-certificates=true`.

And, reload and restart kubelet with:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service kubelet restart
```

After the restart, I see something like `14114 log.go:172] http: TLS handshake error from 20.0.0.13:57738: no serving certificate available for the kubelet`, which indicates that the certificate needs to be added and approve.

Secondly, we need to approve the `csr` from kubernetes (this is something I've never look at before...):

```
kubectl get csr
```

There will see the certificate waiting to be approved, so just approved:

```
kubectl certificate approve csr-dlcf6
```

And your cluster should now have the server kubelet certificate renew. To verify again:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect localhost:10250 2>&1 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' | openssl x509 -text -noout | grep -A 2 Validity
```

Some notes:

- We have enabled the rotation for both client and server. Client rotation is also part of the automatic cert renew script (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/)
- After we have enable the rotation the `/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt` is no longer used, instead the symbolic link `/var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-server-current.pem` is used and points to the latest rotated certificate.

References:

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/
- https://devopstales.github.io/kubernetes/k8s-cert/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tls/certificate-rotation/
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#kubelet-serving-certs

Comment: THANK YOU!!!  Only place I've seen a solution to this after hours of searching